# Will the electrons interact with the e.m wave in the below condition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Suppose if we incident a beam of electromagnetic wave which is produced by overlapping of two e.m waves and the resultant beam is in such a way that the electric field's of the wave oscillate in opposite direction and the two waves are in phase.if we calculate the net electric field such that the two electric fields are equal in magnitude,net result is zero.Then the situation be like as if there is no wave right?.Correct if am wrong,Also is there any possibility for a e.m wave to not interact with electrons.will this situation affect vibrational excitation of molecules.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could do this, the electrons would not see the resultant non-wave.

You can analyze this with water or sound waves, as well as EM waves.  Mathematically, start a sine wave from the left, and another from the right, with the same amplitude and wavelengths, and in phase with each other.  Set this up in your favorite computer modeling software, such as MatLab or Mathematica.

Now compute the sum of the waves at each point, and display with a new color; you will see a flat line, resting on the axis of travel.

Now change the parameters slightly: change one of the amplitudes, or wavelengths, or the phase relationship, or the orientation to be slightly off axis.  Now the plot of the sum will have regions where it is nearly flat, but there will also be regions with enhancement.

Now add an additional element to the graph: the new plot is of the square of the amplitude of the combined waves.  This graph is proportional to the energy.  You will find that the integral of this graph should be equal to the integrals of the corresponding graphs for the two waves; that is, the total energy is conserved, but displaced.

The lesson is this: if one were to have two opposite but equal waves, then they would cancel everywhere. But for this to actually occur, they would have to be of infinite extent, and have existed for all time, and will have overlapped for all time and all space.  And in this case, and only in this case, will the energy disappear everywhere; otherwise it is just displaced.

Thus one can imagine such a scenario, but can never actually do it except over some finite area.  You can actually see such calm areas if you have a nice water table with two sources of waves operating in synch; you can also sometimes see it in nature.

Comment: Is there like a minimum electric field strength for the electrons to interact,Also is there a way to make e.m waves not interact with electrons.

Comment: And also if the electrons couldn't see the resultant wave,then they will not interact with the wave right,does it affect molecular resonance?

Comment: If the region has a null field, there is no electromagnetic interaction.  But when even slightly misaligned, the field is no longer null everywhere, so there will be interactions.

Comment: will there be enough field strength to move the electrons,also does this effect affect molecular vibrational resonance excitation.

Comment: See the first sentence of the posted answer.  And don't forget to accept & up-vote correct answers.

Comment: Thank you,but still one question does it affect molecular resonance?.

Comment: @Anns: if the field is null in the region of the molecule, then it effectively does not exist.  Hence no resonance.